Can SQL column headings be queryable dates?
I have a spreadsheet that tracks scores weekly. I need to recreate it as a SQL table to query it. For each date, I'll be comparing each person's score (Google pie chart), and for each person, I'll be comparing their score from date to date (Google line chart).
Spreadsheet and preferred SQL table structure:

If my SQL column headings are dates, can they be queried as dates or must I structure my SQL table as follows?:

Ideally, I'd like to structure my SQL table identically to the spreadsheet (see first image).

You do want to structure your SQL into name, date, and count. It will make working with the data much easier and faster. You can turn rows into columns with a "pivot". Exactly how depends on the database.

@Schwern OK. Appreciate the advice and explanation. Will familiarise myself with pivot to output data as required.

What do you mean by "SQL table"? Are you migrating to SQLServer? Can query worksheet - explore PowerQuery. However, forcing a spreadsheet to serve as a db is not ideal. For one thing, workbook can get so large to be unmanageable. Regardless of which tool you choose, 'normalized' schema is better.

@June7 I'm creating a custom table in a WordPress database. My host uses MySQL and phpMyAdmin for databases.
